# Is every hypersurface in projective space given by a single equation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, $X=\mathbb{P}_k^n$ be projective space, and let $Y\subset X$ be some irreducible codimension one sub variety (i.e. a hypersurface). Now, I know that we must be able to express $Y$ in the form $\operatorname{Proj}\, (k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a})$ for some $\mathfrak{a}$, but must it be the case that $\mathfrak{a}$ is principal? I know that if we replace Proj with Spec, this is true.

Comment: In proj constructions, the ideals are not well defined. For a hypersurface, there exists such an $\mathfrak{a}$ which is principal, exactly by the affine arguments, using polynomial rings are UFD.

Comment: Is that still true of homogeneous ideals that do not contain the irrelevant ideal? My impression was that for any such semiprime ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of a graded ring $S$, if we set $X=\operatorname{Proj} S$ then the closed subset $V_+(\mathfrak{a})\subseteq X$ with the induced reduced scheme structure is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Proj} S/\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: A hypersurface is defined by $F=0$ where $F$ is a homogeneous polynomial. But it is also defined by $\{Fx_i=0\}, 0\leq i\leq n$.

Comment: Is it true that a hypersurface is by definition defined by a single homogeneous polynomial? Because that's not my definition of a hypersurface, but that is what I would like to prove.

Comment: Yes, every hypersurface (in your definition) can be defined by a single equation.

Comment: What is the proof?

Comment: It follows from the fact that the polynomial ring is a UFD.

Comment: Could you write out what you mean in more detail? For example, if we let $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{a}$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ must be height 1 among homogeneous primes, but why does this imply that it is height 1?

Comment: Outside the irrelevant maximal ideal, it is height one and that is enough to show that it is of height one. May be reading a bit more commutative algebra might help you.

Comment: But who's to say we don't have some inhomogeneous prime $\mathfrak{q}$ such that $0\subsetneq\mathfrak{q}\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: Codimension will ensure that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose a homogeneous element of $\mathfrak a$ and take one of its irreducible factors, say $f$. Using the lexicographic order on monomials, it is easy to prove that $f$ should be homogeneous. We can choose $f$ vanishing on $Y$, then we have $Y\subset V(f)$, an inclusion of irreducible varieties of the same dimension, therefore $Y=V(f)$.

Comment: Detail for "we can choose $f$ vanishing on $Y$": We took $F\in\mathfrak{a}$ homogeneous hence $Y=V(\mathfrak{a})\subseteq V(F)$. Decomposing $F=\prod f_i^{a_i}$ we have $Y\subseteq\cup V(f_i)$ and $Y$ irreducible hence there exist $i$ with $Y\subseteq V(f_i)$.